# Check if Javascript Object only contains falsy values

Tags: javascript, object

I got an object like this :

```
var obj1 = {foo: false, bar: ''};
var obj2 = {foo: false, bar: '1'};
var obj3 = {foo: true,  bar: ''};
var obj4 = {foo: true,  bar: '1'};
```

I want a simple function to check those objects if all of their values are false or not. In this given example only obj1 should trigger a false - cause all of their values are false. `obj2`, `obj3` and `obj4` own at least one value which is true.

Is there a simple solution to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
!Object.keys(obj1).some(function(k) {return obj1[k];});
// Array.some returns true if any callback returns true
// You want true if all return false, aka if none return true
// So just negate Array.some
```

As a more readable method:

```
var ok = true, k;
for( k in obj1) if( obj1.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    if( obj1[k]) {
        ok = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the some function:

```
[ob1, ob2, ob3, obj4].some(function(obj) { return obj.foo })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw with the other implementations of `.some()` you want to return values where all properties are a falsy value, not just where any property is a falsy value as per the OP requirements.

So this will do it

```
function isFalse(obj) {
  return Object
    .keys(obj)
    .every(function (k) {
      return !obj[k];
    });
}
```

See jsFiddle for proof https://jsfiddle.net/0se3yh62/

The other benefit of Object.keys it will only return own properties so you don't have to check in a manual loop.

Answer (score 1):

For each object: if every property value is `false` return `false`, otherwise `true`:

```
var out = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4].map(function (obj) {
  return !Object.keys(obj).every(function (p) {
    return !obj[p];
  })
}); // [false, true, true, true]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pLxsh92f/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
const isObjectFilled = obj => Object.values(obj).filter(value => !!value).length > 0

isObjectFilled(obj1) // false
isObjectFilled(obj2) // true
isObjectFilled(obj3) // true
isObjectFilled(obj4) // true
```

"The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values))

Once i've this array of values, i'm going to filter it by removing each falsy values.

`.filter(value => !!value)` will filter the array by returning only truthy values.

If the length of the filtered array is greater than 0, it means that at least one of the object's values is truthy. Then the function will return `true`

If the filtered array is empty, it means that all of the object's values are falsy. Then the function will return `false`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your answer and explain a bit what you are doing, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more hints.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a dynamic function that would work on any object, so how about just iterating all of the object's indexes?

```
function objIsFalsy(obj) {
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :-

1. Put all your object variables in an array.
2. Make a foreach loop for the above array.
3. Inside the loop check for object key's value.

Answer (score 0):

Loop on your object:

```js
function isFalsyObj(obj) {
  for(var elt in obj) if (obj[elt]!=false) return false;
  return true;
}
var obj1 = {foo: false, bar: ''};
var obj2 = {foo: false, bar: '1'};
var obj3 = {foo: true,  bar: ''};
var obj4 = {foo: true,  bar: '1'};
console.log(isFalsyObj(obj1));//true
console.log(isFalsyObj(obj2));//false
console.log(isFalsyObj(obj3));//false
console.log(isFalsyObj(obj4));//false
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

isvalidObj(obj1); // false

isvalidObj(obj2); // true

```
function isvalidObj(obj){
    for(var i in obj){ 
      if(obj[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```